# Why are bootstrap javascript features not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Gantry template on Joomla! that has bootstrap integrated into it. I wanted to use the bootstrap javascript components, like lightbox, tabs. I added jQuery (no conflict) as mootools is already loaded, and then added the required code. But, it doesn't work as expected. I set up a test page at http://v2.marlownailandbeauty.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=127

Neither the tabs, nor the lightbox work (just below youtube vid). I can't see any JS errors, just wondering why it might not be working? Any bright ideas? :)

Comment: chrome + F12 before even asking what the problem is. There is a debugger in most browsers you should learn to use it.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about firebug. I have posted this because there is no errors listed in the debugger.

Comment: Have you added bootstrap JS file? I faced same issue couple  days ago. Cannot check it because I'm on smartphone right now.

Comment: I have added bootstrap.js file indeed, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code quickly, it seems to me that you load:

jQuery
JQuery no conflict
Mootools 
Various other Mootools scrripts

To the best of my understanding, it's recommended to load jQuery (no conflict) after Mootools and all the other scripts have loaded: source http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries
ie:
jQuery
Mootools
Various other Mootools scrripts
JQuery no conflict

A couple of ways to test this quickly. You could edit the template file directly and change the order, or use an extension like [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) to load the no conflict scripts.

Or a third option ... have you checked if you even need Mootools in your template? You could [use an extension to disable mootools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/mootools/15748) and see what happens. If you are lucky your template will still work well and your site will load faster. And it's easy enough to reverse if mootools is indeed needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I will have a try of them and see how I get on :)

Comment: Hi --

I've tried disabling mootools, but the page content no longer loaded.

I'm now using jquery easy.. and also loading bootstrap in a much better way, but it's still the same. The noconflict file is empty though. I thought it generated the noconflict code? Or do I need to go in and enter them manually? 

Being Joomla! everything is loaded from different files, and so I'm not sure how I can easily change the order of things. I've moved the bootstrap file much further up the list with some fiddling..  I'm baffled! Surely if there were conflicts then issues would show up in the error console?

Comment: I've found another great plugin for managing all the JS. It has moved everything to the footer and tidied it up, but still the same behaviour. It allows disabling of mootools and mootools more, so I disabled mootools more; no change.

Comment: Are you still loading bootstrap.js? It's difficult for me to tell now.

Comment: No... I've given up :/ and removed it. I will just use some joomla! plugins if I need lightboxes, tabs etc. Thanks anyway. This looked interesting(mootools for bootstrap), but still not working properly, so I've abandoned. https://github.com/anutron/mootools-bootstrap

Comment: As long as you have something working for you, that's the main thing. I think life is changing for the beter now that Joomla 3 is built around jQuery and Bootstrap and mootools gone.